# Django celery and notify.js

Tags: django, notifications, celery

Is it possible to use notify.js with Celery in Django?

What I want to achieve is that when certain task is finished I want to have small pop up notification on any page on the site that task has finished or failed.

Or any other solution for this?

Comment: I would think you're able to notify the front-end through things like websockets. Have a look at [django channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) at the risk of falling down the rabbit hole :)

Comment: @LaundroMat thanks. Will have a look.